# How can I trap a string function?

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        first= str(input("Enter First Noun: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Enter alphabet A-Z only! ")

    First_Noun = first.upper()
    First_Rep = "The crimson spots and fins of lucid gold ,"
    First_Replace= First_Rep.replace("gold", (First_Noun))
    print(First_Replace)
```

I cant trap numeric input , hoping someone can help

Answer (score 0):

`str()` cannot possibly raise ValueError, so this code will not work as written.  And `input()` already returns a string, so you don't need `str()` at all.

Use the string method `isalpha()` instead:

```
while True:
    first = input("Enter First Noun: ")
    if first.isalpha():
        break
    print("Enter alphabet A-Z only! ")
```